# Split by whitespace Except KeyWords

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split, whitespace

So I have a string that looks like this:

```
var sentence = "1 is less than 2";
```

Then I have array with key words :

```
var array = ["is less than", "is bigger than"];
```

now I want to split variable sentence using whitespace but ignoring key words:

```
var sentenceArray = ["1", "is less than" , "2"];
```

Any clues how can I do it ?

Ok I am sorry for making this look like a lazy question, therefore, I have made a regex with split that can be used to match a sentence with multiple delimiters. Nothing to complicated, but looks clean. Enjoy:

```
var sentence = "1 is less than 2 and 3";
var sentenceArray = [];
sentenceArray = sentence.split(/(\is less than|and)/g);
alert(sentenceArray);
```

Comment: Have you written anything to achieve that?

Comment: ... This is not a questions/clues website but a questions/answers website.

Comment: That is funny because I saw few questions where people gave clues as answers, but not answers themselves :) What is so bad about giving some a clue ? and I believe that there is nothing wrong with my question ? I have tried looking could not find anything came here?

Comment: There is one thing very wrong with your question: It does not show any research or attempt to solve your issue. It's in a very popular tag ([tag:javascript]) and as such has been quickly identified as a "poor/lazy question" and treated as one. You should always include your research and tries when asking.

Comment: @Kyll I shall remember this for the next time :) My apologies and wish everyone a lovely Monday. Relax :)

Comment: Don't worry, I know how hard it can be at first. Try not to take it personally, most popular tags are _cluttered_ with crap all the time. Any question that falls just a bit outside the rules such as yours is likely to be poorly treated. Read carefully the [help], ask questions on the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com), follow the rules and you'll be just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `array` is array of strings (I omit those curly braces), you can do it this way:

```
var sentence = "1 is less than 2";
var array = ["is less than", "is bigger than"];
var sentenceArray = [];
for(var i in array){
    var s = sentence.split(array[i]);
    if(s[1]){
        sentenceArray.push(s[0].trim());
        sentenceArray.push(array[i]);
        sentenceArray.push(s[1].trim());
        break; // in case there are more than one unique delimiter in the array
    }
}

console.log(sentenceArray);
```

Output:

```
 ["1", "is less than", "2"]
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir :) I am glad there are people not affected by Monday mood :)

Comment: You're welcome - you should edit the question if that's what you were intended to get - remove the curly braces from both arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are. I think you are wrong about array in JS.

```js
var sentence = "1 is less than 2";
var array = ["is less than", "is bigger than"];
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (sentence.indexOf(array[i]) > -1) {
        result.push(array[i]);
        var splitResults = sentence.split(array[i]);
        for (var j = 0; j < splitResults.length; j++) {
            result.push(splitResults[j]);
        }
    }
}
alert(result);
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you, the code works however it returns the string in wrong order :)

Answer (score 0):

Split them on numbers

```js
var sentence = "1 is less than 2";
var sentenceArray  = sentence.split(/(\d+)/g).map(function(a){return a.trim()}).filter(function(a){return a;});
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(sentenceArray);
```